# How can I share Navionics with my iPhone

Tags: iphone

Hi I have Navionics on the iPad (love it) Can i share it onto my iPhone some how?
Cheers Deano

Comment: what do you mean by "share"?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is what Navionics says about that](http://navionics.force.com/kb/articles/en_US/Knowledge_Article/Mobile-Sync-My-Data):

> To turn on the Sync My Data function go to either Archive or Settings
>   in the app menu and turn on the Sync My Data option.
>
> You will be required to create a Navionics Account (or sign into an
>   existing Navionics Account).  Signing into the same Navionics Account
>   on multiple devices will Sync your Favorites data through your Account
>   on our servers.